# jQuery set css attribute lags on fadeIn

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I wrote a simple JQuery code, but every time, when I click on 'eat' the animation has lags. Is there any chance to pre-load this animation?

`#custom_menu` is a full page section with fixed position (something like popup window)

```
$('.eat').click(function(){
    $('#menu').css('opacity', '0');
    $('#custom_menu').css("display", "block").hide().fadeIn(500)
    $('#custom_menu').css("overflow-y", "scroll");
    $('body').css("overflow-y", 'hidden');
});
```

Comment: provide html and if possible a fiddle too

Comment: `.fadeIn(500)` is a 1/2 second animation.  Is that the lag you're referencing?

Answer (score -1):

Why do you use jquery to apply css attributes. Just write custom css class, put all the things there and use jquery to applay and remove that class.

Also, like Steven suggest, try to increase the fadeIn value.